# Linux Not Detecting Windows Machine On Local Network

Tags: linux, windows, networking

I have 2 machines on the network, Linux (192.168.1.3) and Windows (192.168.1.5).

On Windows > Network sharing options > Turn on network sharing == 'On'

When I host a web server on Windows, I'm able to hit it on Linux in browser.
When I host a web server on Linux, I'm unable to hit in Windows browser.

Question 1: What is preventing me from hitting web server on Linux from Windows browser?

I can ping Linux from Windows, but not Windows from Linux.

Question 2: Why can't I ping Windows from Linux?

The following debian command does not reveal the Windows machine:
    ip a | inet

Question 3: Why is the Windows not showing up here?

Running the following Windows command reveals the Linux machine:
    arp -a

Thanks!

Comment: Are you pinging the IP address, or some hostname?

Comment: Do you have samba/cifs?

Comment: Does the Windows box see the ICMP echo request come in? If it does, does it then do an arp who-has for the src address?

Comment: What are the Linux and Windows machine connected to, and how? A home router? LAN? WLAN? If you can't `ping 192.168.1.5` from the Linux machine, then something in-between is blocking it, so we need to know about the stuff in-between ...

Answer (score 0):

Most likey a firewall - You gave not specified your distro but many distro come with a firewall which allow SSH , ICMP and data related to outbound requests only.

(The problem can't be a routing/layer 2 one because everything is on the same subnet and traffic does flow)

Some versions of Windows block some types of ping traffic.